# QMediaPlayer undefined-reference linker errors

Tags: c++, qt

I installed Qt5 and since Phonon is not supported in Qt5 I'm forced to use something else, so I decided to use QtMultimedia.

.pro file:

```
QT       += core gui
CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY += multimedia
```

.cpp code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtMultimedia/QMediaPlayer>

...

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
    player->setVolume(50);
    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("some_path"));
    player->play();
}
```

But I'm getting following errors:

[image]

How can I solve this. Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add *multimedia* module to QT in .pro file, *run qmake* and then build your project:

```
QT += core gui multimedia
```

In Qt 5 that QMediaPlayer class is in multimedia [module](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qtmultimedia-index.html).
And you might want the [widgets](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtwidgets-index.html) module too (i see you have a mainwindow)

LE: Use the include without module folder:

```
#include <QMediaPlayer>
```